# Regex for RM-EC001 (in sql-server)

Tags: sql-server, regex

i have a text and want to find all occurences of: prefix **RM-EC + 3 digit number**. For example *RM-EC001*, *RM-EC099* or *RM-EC100*. But RM-EC99 should not be found.

Thank you.

Comment: What language/regular expression library are you using?

Comment: I want to use RegexMatch from the  RegexLib Library in SQL-Server: http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-regular-expressions-regex-to-sql.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RM\-EC\d{3}
```

As you're using SQL Server, I just found you can't to use quantifiers:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (value varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('RM-EC001')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('RM-EC099')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('RM-EC100')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('RM-EC99' )
SELECT * FROM #test WHERE value LIKE 'RM-EC[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: You might need leading and trailing wild cards as well `'%RM-EC[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'` unless it has to match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression should look like this:

```
RM-EC[0-9]{3}
```

Depending on the regular expression implementation, you could also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a RegEx, but since you also tagged the question as SQL Server, I'll point out that this would also work:

```
WHERE YourColumn LIKE 'RM-EC[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```